# IndexError: list index out of range (Python 3)

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I'm experiencing problems with a Python list. My code requires file storage of 3 variables (item name, id, location) and so I am using a somewhat complex system to approach this. Every item name and its ID are stored in a `.txt` file depending on their location (A location of `myLocation` means they are stored in `myLocation.txt`.) Inside the file, they are stored with one name-ID pair every line, for example:

```
item1, id1
item2, id2
```

The error I'm getting is `IndexError: list index out of range`. I have searched for answers, yet I cannot find a solution that works.

**My code is below:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from time import sleep

# Set variables to be used later
loadedItems = {} # Stores loaded items (as values) and item info (as list keys)

def newItem(name, id, location):
    print("[INFO] Adding new item.")
    try:
        print("[INFO] Checking if " + str(location) + ".txt exists.")
        itemfile = open((str(location) + ".txt"), "a") # Ready to append to file if exists
        print(location + ".txt exists.")
    except:
        print("[INFO] " + str(location) + ".txt does not exist.")
        print("[INFO] Trying to create " + str(location) + ".txt.")
        try:
            itemfile = open((str(location) + ".txt"), "a+") # Creates file if it does not already exist
            print("[INFO] Created " + str(location) + ".txt.")
        except:
            print("[WARN] Could not create " + str(location) + ".txt to store items. Your item was not saved.")
            print("       Try manually creating the file with 'touch " + str(location) + ".txt'.")
            return # Exits function
    print("[INFO] Trying to write to " + str(location) + ".txt.")
    try:
        itemfile.append(str(name) + ", " + str(id) + "\n") # Write to it
        print("[INFO] Wrote to " + location + ".txt.")
    except:
        print("[WARN] Could not write to " + str(location) + ".txt. Your item was not saved.")
        return
    print("[INFO] Wrote to " + str(location) + ".txt.")
    itemfile.close() # Close file
    print("[INFO] Closed " + str(location) + ".txt.")

def loadItems():
    print("[INFO] Loading items.")
    print("[INFO] Trying to open location file.")
    try:
        locfile = open("locations.txt", "r") # Open list of all locations
        print("[INFO] Opened location file.")
    except: 
        print("[INFO] Location file does not exist, creating it.")
        locfile = open("locations.txt", "w+")
        locfile.close()
        print("[INFO] Created and closed location file. Nothing to read.")
        return # exit loadItems()
    print("[INFO] Reading location file.")
    locations = locfile.read().split("\n") # List of locations
    print("[INFO] Read location file. Found " + str(len(locations)) + " locations.")
    locfile.close() # Close location file

    emptyLocs = 0
    emptyItems = 0
    for loc in locations:
        if loc != '': # NOT a blank location
            itemfile = open(loc) # Open location specified in location file
            localItems = itemfile.read().split("\n") # Get list of items and their ids
            print("[DEBUG] localItems: " + str(localItems)) # For debugging purposes, to be removed
            del localItems[-1] # Removes last item from localItems (it is a blank line!)
            print("[DEBUG] localItems: " + str(localItems)) # For debugging purposes, to be removed
            for localItem in localItems: # localItem is misleading, it's actually a list with item name AND id.
                itemInfoToLoad = localItem.split(", ") # Make list with 1st = name and 2nd = id
                loadedItems[itemInfoToLoad[1]] = [itemInfoToLoad[2], ''.join(loc.split())[:-4]] # explained below
                """
                    Explanation of above: create a new key in loadedItems with the name of
                    itemInfoToLoad[1], which is the item name. Set its value to a list that
                    is [id, location]. The ''.join(loc.split())[:-3] is to remove the .txt
                    extension (and any trailing whitespace) so we go from myAwesomeLocation.txt
                    to myAwesomeLocation. Bazinga.
                """
        elif loc == '': # Blank location
            sleep(0.1)
            emptyLocs = (emptyLocs + 1)
    print("[INFO] Loaded variables. Found " + str(emptyLocs) + " empty location entries and " + str(emptyItems) + " empty items.")

loadItems()
```

**Here's my output:**

```
[INFO] Loading items.
[INFO] Trying to open location file.
[INFO] Opened location file.
[INFO] Reading location file.
[INFO] Read location file. Found 2 locations.
[DEBUG] localItems: ['item1, id1', 'item2, id2', '']
[DEBUG] localItems: ['item1, id1', 'item2, id2']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 76, in <module>
    loadItems()
  File "main.py", line 63, in loadItems
    loadedItems[itemInfoToLoad[1]] = [itemInfoToLoad[2], ''.join(loc.split())[:-4]] # explained below
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This seems quite strange. Huge thanks in advance to anyone offering assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in this line:

```
loadedItems[itemInfoToLoad[1]] = [itemInfoToLoad[2], ''.join(loc.split())[:-4]] # explained below
```

you need:

```
loadedItems[itemInfoToLoad[0]] = [itemInfoToLoad[1], ''.join(loc.split())[:-4]] # explained below
```

as you have only two elements in the list

check also loc.split as you have [:-4] in code, and [:-3] in the explanation

Comment: `[:-3]` is a typo - `.txt` is 4 characters long. Otherwise thanks for that, I forgot Python counts from 0.